# How to remove only the curves from a FigureCanvasTkAgg

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

i'm trying to clear only the curves from a FigureCanvasTkAgg when i press a tkinter Button but i don't know how. I'm using tkinter and motplotlib, and the plot is in a Figure from matplotlib.
My functions are in a Class, `init_canvas` is used to create the FigureCanvasTkAgg in my tkinter window, `canvas_draw` is used to create the two curves that i need to remove and `clear_canvas` is used to clear the curves.

Here is my program

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import NavigationToolbar2Tk
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

clear_button = tk.Button(canvas_frame, text="Reset", width=WIDTH_BUTTON-20, font=(FONT, FONT_SIZE), bg=BACKGROUND_BUTTON, command = lambda: self.clear_canvas())
clear_button.grid(row=30, column=1, padx=PADX_WIDGETS, pady=PADY_WIDGETS, sticky='ne')

def init_canvas(self):
        self.figure_plot = Figure(figsize=(6,6), dpi = 100) 
        self.figure_axis = self.figure_plot.add_subplot(111)
        self.figure_axis.grid()

        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.figure_plot, self.second_frame)
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

        toolbar_plot = NavigationToolbar2Tk(self.canvas, self.second_frame)
        toolbar_plot.update()
        self.canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

 def canvas_draw(self, freq, reel, imag):
        self.figure_one = self.figure_axis.plot(freq, reel, color ='Blue') #NEED TO REMOVE
        self.figure_two = self.figure_axis.plot(freq, imag, color ='Green')  #NEED TO REMOVE
        self.figure_axis.grid()
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
        self.canvas.draw()
        self.canvas.blit()

def clear_canvas(self):
        return 0
        # self.figure_plot.clear()
        # self.figure_plot.add_subplot(111)         
        # self.canvas.draw_idle()
        # self.figure_axis.grid()

        # for item in self.canvas.get_tk_widget().find_all():
        #     self.canvas.get_tk_widget().delete(item)
        #self.toolbar_plot.get_tk_widget().delete()
```

I tried multiples things, like removing one by one all the widgets or clear all the plot, but i don't want my axis to be remove or my toolbar too.